# How to speed up aftreg estimation?

Tags: r, survival, optimization, accelerated-failure-time

I am performing an Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) regression data on a panel setting (multiple records per observation with time-dependent variables) using the `eha` package in `R`. The dataset is relatively large (162,541 records, 15,537 observations)

However, the estimation takes too long compare to STATA. Are there any configurations that can boost the `aftreg` function's performance?

here are my current configurations:

```
aftreg(
    formula = Surv(t0,t1,event) ~ PLD + state, 
    dist = "weibull", 
    data = dta , 
    param ="lifeExp",
    control = list(eps = 1, maxiter = 20, trace = TRUE),
    id = id)
```

PLD is a dummy variable.
state is a categorical variable (factor).

Comment: If this is about the performanmce of an R function, maybe stackoverflow is a better place?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen it depends. The options might be specified based on the function itself, or the econometric properties of the data.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to aftreg you can try the penAFT package in R. It's pretty straightforward to use. You can find it on CRAN and an example of how to use it is available here: https://ajmolstad.github.io/docs/penAFT_Example.html